# PHP print xml file in pretty format

Tags: php, xml, pretty-print

I need to display one XML file in browser through Apache request. So I can serve the file to freeswitch. My PHP code is like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("not found");
echo "<pre>".print_r($xml,true)."</pre>";
?>
```

But I get this output:

```
<pre>SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [type] => freeswitch/xml
    )

[section] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [name] => configuration
            )

        [configuration] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [description] => Network Lists
                        [name] => acl.conf
                    )

                [network-lists] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [list] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => localhost_allow
                                                [default] => allow
                                            )

                                        [node] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [type] => allow
                                                        [cidr] => 127.0.0.1/32
                                                    )
)
</pre>
```

I just need a pretty xml output in browser. Or I can serve xml files in another way. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to load the XML-file as object.
Just load the raw content of the file and print it:

```
$file = file_get_contents("test.xml");
echo $file;
```

Browsers will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will do the trick, if not, I believe you have to parse the xml and then you can format it as you wish.

```
 <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("not found");
    echo $xml->asXML();
 ?>
```